# Populate count of unique items in array-based fields across all documents

Tags: mongodb, sails.js

I have documents that have `category` field as array of strings, like

```
{ name: "aaa", categories: ["apple","banana","peach"] },
{ name: "bbb", categories: ["apple","orange" },
{ name: "ccc", categories: ["apple","peach"] }
...
```

In result I need to have and array of objects having aggregated values of each unique value from category and number of occurances of this category, like this:

```
[
    { category: "apple", qty: 3 },
    { category: "banana", qty: 1 },
    { category: "peach", qty: 2 },
    { category: "orange", qty: 1 }
]
```

I have tried the following, but it produces empty array in result

```
SomeCollection.native(function(err, collection) {
    collection.aggregate([
        { $group: { _id: "$categories", name: { $addToSet: "$categories._type" } } },
        { $unwind: "$categories" },
        { $group : { _id : "$categories", count: { $sum : 1 } } }
    ], function(error, result) {
        sails.log.info('result:', result);  
    });
});
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is returning an empty result because your first pipeline step is a **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** piped operation which is essentially grouping all the documents in your collection by the `categories` array, at the same time you are adding to an array in that perculiar group the array type. The empty result follows when you apply the **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** operator on to a non-existing array field (because the previous **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** operator pipeline does not produce a new `categories` field, only the keys `_id` and `name`).

You'd want to first of all flatten the `categories` array so that it will generate a new record for each and every element of the categories data field on which **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** is applied. Now you can then apply the **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** operation to get the desired result:

Consider the following approach:

```
SomeCollection.native(function(err, collection) {
    collection.aggregate([
        { $unwind: "$categories" },
        { $group: { _id: "$categories", qty: { $sum : 1 } } }
    ], function(error, result) {
        sails.log.info('result:', result);  
    });
});
```